# How do I force the Windows MSI installer to perform a complete install?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, unattended

I have a Windows MSI installer package which gives me the choice to do a Typical, Custom or Complete install using the GUI.

The default (typical) install only installs some components.

How to I tell it to do a complete install from the command line using the `/passive` switch?

The installer version is: `5.0.7600`.

Answer (score 2):

---

**UPDATE June 2018**: Although the tool shown below is no longer available for download, I found it via Wayback machine. I assume it is OK and legal to link to it, seeing as the tool was freeware. Updated links below.

<del>**UPDATE**: *This tool from Wise is regrettably not downloadable anymore*. I am not sure if it is OK to distribute it either. It seemed to be a free tool distributed as part of their main Wise Package Studio suite, but I don't think it is open source. I wish they would release it as an open source tool.</del>

The Wise packaging products have been discontinued due to a number of [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions,_Inc.).

---

On a related note. To deal with the ridiculously complex command line for msiexec.exe you can use this free **msi command line builder tool** from Wise: [http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20140402194132/http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe) (**resurrected from Wayback machine**).

Please run the download by [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) for safety.

It allows you to build a command line interactively:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ADDLOCAL=ALL to the overall msiexec.exe command. Something like:

`C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /I "D:\winzip112.msi" /QN ADDLOCAL=ALL`

More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367536(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: that link says "Do not enter ADDLOCAL=ALL into the Property Table, because this generates a locally installed package that cannot be correctly removed"

Comment: @rik that means do not insert it into the MSI file. Properties passed on the commandline don’t go in the property table.

Comment: @user193452: yes, don't set ADDLOCAL in the Property table, set it on the command line for msiexec.exe. Very different operations.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the installer as to what command switches will work. Typically, the /passive switch does a full install. However, sometimes you need to set properties in order to trigger it, and the properties are not always available online.

Check out: http://www.instedit.com/

Using this program you can open up MSI packages and alter the properties to set them to what you want. The good part is you can resave the MSI package so your property values can be reused, which is great for deployment. It says you have to pay but just download the free version and your good. It has a slight learning curve, but it is not too difficult. The search feature is your friend!

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please give an explaination as to why. I use InstEd to open MSIs all the time when the standard switches don't work as expected.