# Screwed up SolidWorks 2014 installation on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, solidworks

I was trying to install SolidWorks 2014, but it took so long that i had to break off the installer. Now trying to start it up again, Windows thinks Solidworks is already fully installed but can't find the correct files. Trying to fix this, i permanently deleted all the files related to Solidworks. When trying to reinstall SolidWorks, it asks if I want to uninstall first, if clicked yes it tries to startup SolidWorks and this off course does not work (error 1603). if no, it just stops the installer.

How do I fix this? Please help?

Comment: Have you tried using `/force ` on the installer?

Comment: here is how to use /force on the installer http://superuser.com/questions/240861/how-do-i-force-the-windows-msi-installer-to-perform-a-complete-install

Comment: Still gives the same error: SolidWorks is already installed. Do you want to uninstall SolidWorks now?